# Thymeleaf - How to dynamically add a tooltip to a table cell upon a condition

Tags: css, thymeleaf

We are building a dynamic table with Thymeleaf.

Some cells, of null values, are holding "-" sign, while cells with values hold some  data from the object:

```
<td th:text="${person.getAddress()} ? ${person.getAddress().getCity() : '-'"}
```

So the current state is this:

```html
<table border=1>
<tr><td>John</td><td>London</td></tr>
<tr><td>Paul</td><td>-</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now, we like to add a tooltip, that when hovering the relevant table cell, more data can be seen (e.g. the person's full address).

We found [this CSS example for tooltip](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp) and we figure out our final result should be something like that:

```
<td class="tooltip">London
  <div class="tooltiptext">
     <div>Street: Green</div>
     <div>Number: 123</div>
  </div>
</td>
```

But when trying to implement it in Thymeleaf we got stuck.

This is what we tried:

```
<div th:switch="${person.getAddress()}">
  <div th:case="null"><td>-</td></div>
  <div th:case="*">
      <td> // now what? how to both inject value and the sub divs? </td>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another option we thought of is to create by concatenation the full HTML within a `td th:text=...`

But both of the ways seems very cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use the [safe navigation operator](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-operator-safe-navigation) in combination with the [elvis operator](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#default-expressions-elvis-operator) instead of your null check.
2. No need for switch or any logic like this. Create a couple extra tags and move your logic deeper into the html.
3. Don't use `.getAddress()`, you can just use `.address` for properties with correctly named getters/setters.

For example:

```
<td>
  <span th:text="${person.address?.city} ?: '-'" />
  <div th:unless="${person.address == null}" class="tooltiptext">
     <div>Street: Green</div>
     <div>Number: 123</div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Without all the fancy stuff, you could also simply do something like this:

```
<td th:if="${person.address == null}">-</td>
<td th:if="${person.address != null}">
  <span th:text="${person.address.city}" />
  <div class="tooltiptext">
     <div>Street: Green</div>
     <div>Number: 123</div>
  </div>
</td>
```